# UWP MediaPlaybackList popping sound in between list items

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, streaming

I am using a MediaPlaybackList to essentially 'stream' audio data coming in via Bluetooth as a byte[] on a fixed time gather interval. According to the MS documentation, MediaPlaybackList is 'gapless' playback between audio samples. But in my case, I have a popping sound and gap when transitioning to the next audio sample.

```
byte[] audioContent = new byte[audioLength];
chatReader.ReadBytes(audioContent);

MediaPlaybackItem mediaPlaybackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromStream(new MemoryStream(audioContent).AsRandomAccessStream(), "audio/mpeg"));
playbackList.Items.Add(mediaPlaybackItem);

if (_mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackState != MediaPlaybackState.Playing)
{               
    _mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play(); ;
}
```

How can I achieve truly 'gapless' streaming audio using a method similar to this?

Also, I have tried writing my stream to a file realtime as the data comes in just to see if the popping sound or the gap is there. It plays from the file that the bytes are appended to perfectly with no pop or gap.

```
using (var stream = await playbackFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    await stream.WriteAsync(audioContent, 0, audioContent.Length);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean that if you create `MediaPlaybackItem ` from stream, it will have popping sound? If you create it from storage file, it plays without pop or gap?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT well one approach I took was trying to take the stream and saving it to a temporary StorageFile first. Then, setting the MediaPlaybackItem from that StorageFile. Ended up with the same results. 

The issue must be with concatenating the byte[] portions of the streamed audio. But how come when I just continuously write it to one file, the playback is just fine?

Answer (score 0):

The MediaPlayer and in particular the MediaPlayerList is not designed to be used with a "live" audio stream. You must finish writing the data to the byte stream before adding it to the list and starting the MediaPlayer. Using the MediaPlayer is not the correct solution for this particular scenario.

A better solution would be to use the [Audio Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs). The Audio Graph allows you to add input sources from actual audio endpoints so you don't need to fill the byte buffer with the streaming audio. You can then use sub-mix nodes to mix between the audio endpoint streams with no clicks or pops.